# How can pass Jquery global variable to arguments in a function?

Tags: jquery, variables, resize, global-variables, argument-passing

I want change table width when window going to resize, as I need to pass my global variable to a function as argument, but when I pass variables its not working and can't use variable in the method, how can I fix that, thanks for your help.

```
var WOS = document.body.parentNode.clientWidth; 
var HOS = document.body.parentNode.clientHeight;
$(window).resize(function(){    
   tableSetup(WOS, HOS);
}

function tableSetup(WOS, HOS) {
   alert(WOS); // give undefined message 
}
```

Comment: who is calling `tableSetup`

Comment: sorry, i had mistake to write script in here, i corrected that

Comment: Still missing closing `)` for `resize` event handler i.e. `$(window).resize(function(){    
   tableSetup(WOS, HOS);
});`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j9k8pkwz/1/ - works just fine

Comment: Where is this code executing in your page?  In the `<head>` section?  Or elsewhere?

Comment: into document function : $(document).ready(function(e) { })

Comment: this code excusing in a js file that called in head of html page like that: <head><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script></head>

Comment: @Arun P Johny thanks for your test but it should change the variable number when window doing resize but It's static even window have 500% zoom in or out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to get the updated values on resize, you need to calculate teh values in the resize event

```js
var WOS = document.body.parentNode.clientWidth;
var HOS = document.body.parentNode.clientHeight;
$(window).resize(function() {
  WOS = document.body.parentNode.clientWidth;
  HOS = document.body.parentNode.clientHeight;
  tableSetup(WOS, HOS);
})

function tableSetup(WOS, HOS) {
  snippet.log(WOS); // give undefined message 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j9k8pkwz/)